# Ember.js: yield specific object in layouts

Tags: ember.js

I would like to create a layout in which I iterate over a collection with `#each` and then pass that object to yield. Is that possible?

What I would like achieve is:

```
<!-- timeline_layout.hbs -->
<div id="timeline-container">
  {{#each entry in controller}}
    <div class='timeline-entry'>
      {{yield entry}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}  
</div>

<!-- timeline_instance.hbs (timeline with posts) -->
{{#view App.Timeline}} <!-- has layout set to timeline_layout -->
  {{render 'post' entry}}
{{/view}}
```

If guess that is not possible, right? Since `render 'post'` can't know about the entry. So what is the ember way to encapsulate the general html structure of the timeline?

Comment: i'm not quite sure if i understand what you want, but shouldn't putting `{{view App.TimelineEntryView contentBinding="entry"}}` or something like that into your `each` do the trick?

Comment: The problem is that the timeline can contain things with different types, e.g. posts, comments, image_uploads. I.e. for every "action" of the system there will be a timeline entry. So basically the TimelineEntryView should render a different template based on the type of the object.

Comment: well, then just use multiple views and `{{#if}}`.

Answer (score 0):

"A template used as a layout must contain a single use of the Handlebars {{yield}} helper. "  [ember.js views](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html). Your approach essentially breaks this rule, as you're trying to create a new yield for each entry in your controller- you should look at refactoring your each into the template.